# Password Char matching user input

Tags: c#, char, passwords

This code is suppose to add a char "*" for every number added to the input variable. Every time you click the button it should add a * to a textbox. It works for the first one but then it doubles every time after that. Any advise what to change?

```
 String input;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Security Code variables
            securityCodeTextBox.Text = "";
            securityCodeTextBox.PasswordChar = '*';
            securityCodeTextBox.MaxLength = 5;

            securityCodeTextBox.PasswordChar = '*';            
            accessLogBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.accessLogBox.Text = "";
            input += 1;
            this.securityCodeTextBox.Text  += input;
            this.accessLogBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.accessLogBox.Text = "";
            input += 2;
            this.securityCodeTextBox.Text += input;
            this.accessLogBox.Text += input;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you `+= 1` to a string variable?

Comment: Is this a WinForms textbox? They already support this with the [`TextBox.PasswordChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_PasswordChar) property.

Comment: That's not what he was asking for help with @DourHighArch, so this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you click a button, you append a number to `input` then append `input` to the `Text`.  So `Text` is increasing at a "greater rate" than `input`.

So each button (let's say `button1`) click you get something like:

> 1->11 ->111   ->1111
>   1->111->111111->1111111111
>   etc.

Seems like you want `...Text=input` rather than `...Text+=input`

Comment: @JeffRyan.  If this answered your question (I believe it did as you previously posted), please mark my answer as the answer (checkbox on the left) to allow future users who may have a similar issue, easily see what solved your problem.